# Use SQL to find the data set that will create the largest size file extract

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are testing a new system's ability to import large CSV files that have been exported from an older system.  I wanted to create the largest export file possible in the old system, so I tried to find our client with the most customers.  That's not hard in itself, but since I'm going for the biggest file size I also need to account for the customers with the most categories assigned to them.

The CSV layout looks like this:

```
FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, CATEGORY|CATEGORY|..., DATE_ADDED
```

The table structure looks like this, where a customer can have one to many categories:

```
CUSTOMER        CUSTOMERCATEGORY       CATEGORY
--------        ----------------       --------
customerid      customerid             categoryid
firstname       categoryid             description     
lastname
email
clientid
dateadded
```

This builds my file (for client 9999):

```
select firstname, 
    lastname, 
    emailaddress, 
    coalesce(LEFT(CategoryNames,LEN(CategoryNames) - 1),'') as categories, 
    date_added
from Customer r
  cross apply
   (Select cc.description + '|'
    FROM Category cc
    join CustomerCategory c on c.categoryid = cc.categoryid
    WHERE r.customerid = c.customerid
    For XML PATH('')) x (CategoryNames)
where r.ClientID = 9999
```

So to get a pretty big file extracted, I looked for the top 20 Clients with the most Customers.  Then I looked for the top 20 Clients with the most Categories assigned to customers, and manually compared the 2 lists to find a client that *probably* has the largest list possible. BUT - it turns out that isn't right because the client that just has the largest customer list and has no categories assigned actually has a bigger file.

How could you find the client with the largest set of data?  I need to test the new system's ability to import these files, and given thousands of clients I do not want to create the CSV for each one because that would take too long.

Comment: You are asking for SQL Server to peek into csv files, do set operations on the rows and yet not read them into SQL Server? Can it then get my kids to do their homework?

Comment: No @benjaminmoskovits I am not.  The data is in SQL Server.  I want to use that data to create CSVs (which I can).  I am curious how you would find the largest set of data to build the CSV with.

Comment: I apologize for not understanding your question.

Comment: Short of extracting the data I don't think it would be possible to determine which one would result in the most bytes of information. Maybe you could change up your query to get the sum of len of every column and then a sum of those values across all rows for each customer. Unfortunately by the time you write a query to do that you would be able to just extract the best 10 guesses and look at the output.

Comment: I would think the DV is due to the question being unclear. I think you're trying to figure out the disk cost for some segment of your data were it to be exported to disk. I think you're basically looking at concatenating all the columns of interest, across all the tales, grabbing the length and then summing by your partitioning key. Writing that in a generic manner is nothing I'd want to do

Comment: @billinkc Thanks for the info.  I guess I didn't think it was unclear.  I will attempt to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would that take too long?

```
select s = sum(len(firstname) + len(lastname) + len(emailaddress) +
       len(coalesce(LEFT(CategoryNames,LEN(CategoryNames) - 1),'')))
     , r.ClientID 
from Customer r
  cross apply
   (Select cc.description + '|'
    FROM Category cc
    join CustomerCategory c on c.categoryid = cc.categoryid
    WHERE r.customerid = c.customerid
    For XML PATH('')) x (CategoryNames)
group by r.ClientID
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: This works - though it will take a *really* long time to run (for just 3 clients out of 4000 it took over 3 minutes - that is summing up the length of approximately 1 million rows).

Answer (score 0):

use something like this for determine which customer have more categories

```
HAVING count(*) = (
    SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) FROM CUSTOMERCATEGORY GROUP BY customerid)
```

for your question it's something like this

```
-- Select fields
select firstname, 
    lastname, 
    emailaddress, 
    coalesce(LEFT(CategoryNames,LEN(CategoryNames) - 1),'') as categories, 
    date_added 
  from Customer r join CUSTOMERCATEGORY cc on  r.customerid = cc.categoryid                          
  join Category c on cc.categoryid = c.categoryid

-- Filtering the results can do it
where customerid in 
    (select customerid from CUSTOMER  having count(curstomerid)=(select MAX(COUNT(*)) from CUSTOMERCATEGORY group by customerid )
```